# How to use SOCI C++ Database library?

Tags: c++, mysql, database, wrapper, soci

I'm trying to implement soci in my program but I don't know how.  I'm using C++ on Linux, on a project using netbeans. I have followed the steps in: http://soci.sourceforge.net/doc/structure.html to install it, and I tried to copy the files soci.h from /src/core and soci-mysql.h from /src/backends/mysql in my project but it gives a compilation error (these files include other soci files, but it's illogical to copy all files into the directory...). I have read the guide several time but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. The examples only include these files.

Thanks.

Edit: I have given more information in a comment below the answer. I don't know what steps I have to follow to implement soci.

Comment: Did you actually run `make install`? There's no need to copy header files to your project's directory.

Comment: I did ran that command. If I don't copy those files the compiler gives a error saying that the files soci.h and soci-mysql.h weren't found. I just copies the following includes from a example on the documentation: [code] #include "soci.h" #include "soci-mysql.h" [/code] but it didn't work, the compiler said that those files didn't exist, so I tried to copy them from the soci package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The relevant bit on that page is

> When the configure script is run without parameters, the remaining part of the process will use `/usr/local/include/soci` as a default destination for SOCI header files and `/usr/local/lib` as a default destination for library files

Now /usr/local/include ought to be in your default include path (e.g. try something like `gcc -c -v -x c++ /dev/null -o /dev/null` to see the list your install uses) and so you can include these using

```
#include <soci/soci.h>
#include <soci/soci-mysql.h>
```

You then need to add the libraries to your link step. It looks like you'll have both static and shared versions of the libraries. You'll need to add `-lsoci_core -lsoci_mysql` to your link step; however if that doesn't work then you'll also need to specify /usr/local/lib as a search directory i.e. `-L/usr/local/lib -lsoci_core -lsoci_mysql`. (Again it's probably there already but you can see using `gcc -print-search-dirs`.) However, the issue then is that if you're using the shared version and /usr/local/lib isn't in your distributions library search path (see /etc/ld.so.conf and/or /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*) then it won't be able to find the shared library at runtime. You'll need to either hard-code in the path to the library with the linker switch `-rpath` or add /usr/local/lib to the system-wide search path as before or in your environment (variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`). I'm not sure what the best way to do this is - I'd suggest `-rpath` to avoid modifying the system in general, although if you're building a lot of libraries into /usr/local/lib it might make sense to add it.

Comment: The library throws the exception "Failed to find shared library for backend mysql" even specifying /usr/local/lib as a search directory and -rpath, but I could solve it copying the three mysql backend .so files to the project directory.  Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I might have that wrong then: it's possible you only need to link in `-lsoci_core` and then it will dlopen the mysql library itself? It's odd it can't then find the library, though, as it would have known that /usr/local/lib would be the place to look at build time. Sorry, I don't know soci specifically to suggest anything better but glad you got it working!

Comment: No, I have just tried that and it doesn't work without the -lsoci_mysql option. I don't know why, but soci also  attemps to dlopen the mysql backend library. I found the file where that happens searching the previus error on google: http://code.google.com/p/boost-soci/source/browse/trunk/libs/soci/src/backend-loader.cpp?r=2 PD: Can you tell me how you put "code tags" on comments?

Comment: Neast - from that file it looks like you could have also set environment variable `SOCI_BACKENDS_PATH` to /usr/local/lib. Sure, you can surround code with backticks ` in comments. I've also seen people link text somehow but I don't know how to do that, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same **doesn't load backend** error on my C++ program when I execute `session sql("mysql://db=...)`

I found a solution (at least on my Ubuntu 11.04). Just do:

```
sudo -i ln -s /usr/lib/libsoci_mysql-gcc-3_0-3.0.0.so /usr/lib/libsoci_mysql.so
```

It seem that the SOCI library search for the file `/usr/lib/libsoci_mysql.so` that is not in the system, buy if you make a link to the library `/usr/lib/libsoci_mysql-gcc-3_0-3.0.0.so` that it's in the system it works (I think debian/ubuntu makes a file name change from the original name, but it have side effects because the SOCI library search inside for the original name).

I found the error using the bash environment variable `LD_DEBUG=files` and running my C++ binary.

Hope it helps.